# How to round up time to nearest quarter but only if the time is 1 minute or more over a quarter?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If cell A1 contains time duration 1:01 and I want to round it up in cell A2 to the nearest quarter - to 1:15, it can be done with the formula =CEILING(A1,"0:15").
But what I need is that if the cell A1 is 1:00, the result in A2 must be 1:00. So I only need the time duration to be rounded up to the nearest quarter IF the time duration is 1 minute or more over a quarter, eg. 1:01 or 1:46 etc. Is there a formula that would solve the problem for me?
Examples of what results I need to get:
A1  >>      A2
1:45        >>      1:45
1:31    >>      1:45
3:02    >>      3:15
3:15    >>      3:15

Comment: Try this =IF(MOD(MINUTE(A1),15)=0,A1,CEILING(A1,"0:15"))

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much patkim, you saved my life :)

Comment: @patkim post as an answer

Comment: I've deleted my post as @patkim solution is neater and more responsive to your problem as stated.  Although to avoid any possible issues with a user having a time separator other than the colon, I would use `TIME(0,15,0)` rather than `"0:15"`

Comment: One can also use MROUND: `=MROUND(A1+TIME(0,7,29),TIME(0,15,0))`